# Access hidden value from View to Controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need help for passing hidden control values from the ASP.NET Core razor view page using jQuery.

jQuery is used to fetch dynamic control selected values:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("button[type='submit']").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var properties = [];
                $("#tb_properties tr").each(function (index, item) {
                    var $row = $(item), $td = $row.find('td');
                    $td.each(function (i, td) {
                        var propertyname = $td.find("input[type='text']").val();
                        var selctedvalue = $td.find("select").val();
                        properties.push('"' + propertyname + '":"' + selctedvalue + '"');
                    })

                });
                var jsonstr = '{' + properties.join(",") + '}';
                var jsobject = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonstr));
                console.log(jsonstr);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "/Home/Insert",
                    //data: jsobject,
                    data: jsonstr,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        toastr.info(response.status + "<br>" + "<br>" + response.message);
                        $("#tb_properties select").val("");
                        $("#partial_div").load(window.location.href + " #partial_div");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('in error');
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This jQuery is working fine. Need to pass one more hidden control value through jQuery to the below controller HTTP post insert method. Can anybody please help me?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Insert([FromBody] JObject jsonModel)
        {
            if (jsonModel != null)
            {
                List<K360mapMaster> K360mapListObj = new List<K360mapMaster>();

                foreach (JProperty prop in jsonModel.Children())
                {
                    string key = prop.Name.ToString();
                    string value = prop.Value.ToString();
                    //!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)                    
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    {
                        K360mapListObj.Add(new K360mapMaster() { ClientCatalog = key, K360catalog = value });
                    }
                }
                if (K360mapListObj.Count > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _context.K360mapMasters.AddRange(K360mapListObj);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(new { Status = "Success", Message = "No conflicts. Catalogs mapped." });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        TempData["ExceptionmsgM"] = ex;                        
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    return Json(new { Status = "Error", Message = "Catalogs not selected." });
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Comment: Can you share the example data that you want to send through ajax request?

Comment: @FeiHan sorry for the late response. I have changed my approach and find the solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get data from View in Controller

```
form.request['name of element'];
```

Comment: I need through jQuery. Moreover your suggestion I tried but it's not working