# How to return multiple values from api to HttpClient Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, pagination

I need help with returning multiple values from my api to the httpclient post request but its returning null

**api**

```
[HttpPost("ShowUser")]
    public (IEnumerable<UserInformation>, int) ShowUser([FromBody] Pagination pagination)
    { // retrieving data from database 
        var result = _showUsers.ShowManagerUsers(pagination.PageSize, pagination.skip, pagination.searchValue); // the output here is({System.Collections.Generic.List<Entities.UserInformation>}, 37) (note: 37 is the rows total)
        Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>> paginationResponse = new Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>>
        {
            Data = result.Item1,
            RowsCount = result.Item2
        };
        return (paginationResponse.Data, paginationResponse.RowsCount);
    }
```

**HttpClient Post Request**

```
public async Task<(List<TOut>, TOut)> PostGetListRequest<TIn, TOut>(TIn content, string uri, string token)
    {
            ...

            using (response = await client.PostAsync(uri, serialized))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                {
                    responseBody =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(List<TOut>, TOut)>(responseBody);
                    return (result.Item1, result.Item2);
                }
                  ...
            }
    }
```

**Output**
[image]

[image]

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your API code to this.

```
    [HttpPost("ShowUser")]
    public ActionResult ShowUser([FromBody] Pagination pagination)
    { // retrieving data from database 
        var result = _showUsers.ShowManagerUsers(pagination.PageSize, pagination.skip, pagination.searchValue); // the output here is({System.Collections.Generic.List<Entities.UserInformation>}, 37) (note: 37 is the rows total)
        Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>> paginationResponse = new Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>>
        {
            Data = result.Item1,
            RowsCount = result.Item2
        };
        return Ok((paginationResponse.Data, paginationResponse.RowsCount));
    }
```

If this is is designed to be an API that others will consume, you really shouldn't be returning anonymous objects. I think it would be a better idea to either return a wrapper model, or simply return the pagingResponse model you already have.

```
    [HttpPost("ShowUser")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public ActionResult ShowUser([FromBody] Pagination pagination)
    { // retrieving data from database 
        var result = _showUsers.ShowManagerUsers(pagination.PageSize, pagination.skip, pagination.searchValue); // the output here is({System.Collections.Generic.List<Entities.UserInformation>}, 37) (note: 37 is the rows total)
        Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>> paginationResponse = new Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>>
        {
            Data = result.Item1,
            RowsCount = result.Item2
        };
        return Ok(paginationResponse);
    }
```

Let me know if this doesn't work or if you need anything else.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I tried ur solution it worked but I don't know if there is a way to deserialize two object (data, rowcount)

Comment: Hi there. I'm glad it solved your issue. Short answer is no, it's considered bad practice. As I said, the correct approach is to either return the paginationResponse or create a wrapper model. Keep it simple. :) 

If you really want to return a tuple, you will need to create a custom converter on your API - which would essentially just result in you returning a wrapper model anyway. If you really want to go with this approach, you can read through this example. 

[json converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm?msclkid=78100406d03b11eca5b679e3384e775b)

Answer (score 0):

1-you should await for reading response content

```js
                    responseBody =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

2-Make Sure the response in not empty.

3- i discourage using tuples as it violates the Object orinted and clean code practices

Comment: I removed await to be able to read the result as (result.item1, result.item2)

Answer (score 0):

1. For the empty response body, if your project version is **beyond ASP.NET Core 3.x**, be sure add NewtonSoft support, check [detailed steps in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65101721/11398810)

   ```
   services.AddControllers()
       .AddNewtonsoftJson();
   ```
2. Assume that the `PostGetListRequest<TIn, TOut>` method is invoked by using the following code, `TOut` is type of `UserInformation` class:

   ```
   await GetListRequest<string, UserInformation>("xxx", "https://localhost:portNumber/xxx", "xxx");
   ```

   So the deserialize type should be `(List<UserInformation>, UserInformation)`.

   ```
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(List<TOut>, TOut)>(responseBody);
   ```

   But your API's return type is `(IEnumerable<UserInformation>, int)`.

   ```
   public (IEnumerable<UserInformation>, int) ShowUser([FromBody] Pagination pagination)
   ```

   **API's return type does not match the deserialize type**. So you cannot deserialize successfully.

A working demo:

```
public async Task<(List<TOut>, int)> GetListRequest<TIn, TOut>(TIn content, string uri, string token)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri,serialized);
            
    var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<(List<TOut>, int)>(responseBody);
    return (result.Item1, result.Item2);
}
```

Api:

```
[HttpPost("ShowUser")]
public (IEnumerable<UserInformation>, int) ShowUser([FromBody] Pagination pagination)
{ // retrieving data from database 
    var result = _showUsers.ShowManagerUsers(pagination.PageSize, pagination.skip, pagination.searchValue); // the output here is({System.Collections.Generic.List<Entities.UserInformation>}, 37) (note: 37 is the rows total)
    Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>> paginationResponse = new Entities.PaginationResponse<IEnumerable<UserInformation>>
    {
        Data = result.Item1,
        RowsCount = result.Item2
    };
    return (paginationResponse.Data, paginationResponse.RowsCount);
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank u @Rena for helping my but I'm still getting a null result

Comment: Hi, are you sure your api actually return data? Do you debug your code?

Comment: I tested my api in Postman its returning null I don't know why

Comment: Hi, you need set breakpoint to your api and debug it step by step to check which line does not contain value... Especially check the `result` in the `ShowUser` method. BTW, does the frombody parameter `Pagination pagination` receives the value?

Comment: yes pagination receives values, and result output is (the list and the count) but api return null

Comment: Hi, How is your `paginationResponse`? Do you check its value?